# Pass whole object or just attribute from view to controller via ngClick in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Should we pass whole object or just the required attribute from view to controller in AngularJS?

For example:

**View**

```
<div ng-repeat="house in town">
    <div ng-click="listHome( house.id )"></div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.listHome = function (id) {
    // do something with id
}
```

Let's assume the controller function only requires the `id` of `house` and not the whole object.

Is it advisable for performance to pass `house.id`, or pass the whole `house` object and then split out the `id` on the controller side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both way will not make any difference on performance.

I'd just say that 1st case would be an example of `pass by value` & the second one can be considered as `pass by reference`.

### **Lets understand what I said**

When you just pass particular property to method like `ng-click="listHome(house.id)"` and you modify that `houseid` inside method, that would not change the actual object reference because you just passed the value.

Whereas if you pass the `house` object itself like  `ng-click="listHome(house)"` & then you modified any of the object property, so that will change actual object which reference has been passed to that method.

---

Its upto you, which approach to follow. If you just wanted to pass `id` of `house` & do something else the go for 1st approach.

If you wanted to change the current reference of object by validating something in code then go for 2nd approach.

Answer (score 1):

The performance is hardly going to make a real difference. Passing an object to a function is basically free.

If you just require the `id`, then only pass the `id`. Not for performance reasons, but for clarity reasons. It's generally a good practice to only pass arguments you really need to a function.